# Removing characters from decrypted Base64 string in Java

Tags: java, android, encryption, base64, initialization-vector

In relation to this question; [Java (Android) Decrypting msg with IV attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447412/java-android-decrypting-msg-with-iv-attached)

My message decrypts fine but with the unwanted IV byte data.
I try to remove the attached IV, yet it does not delete all the characters and some character always remain behind. I'm not sure how I should be calculating the length of the encoded IV to remove the non-required characters.

```
public String decrypt(String cipherText, byte[] encryptionKey) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey, "AES");          
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iV);
    String decrypt = new String(cipher.doFinal( Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT)));

    byte[] decryptData = new byte[decrypt.getBytes().length - iV.getIV().length];
    System.arraycopy(decrypt.getBytes(), iV.getIV().length, decryptData, 0, decrypt.getBytes().length - iV.getIV().length);

    Log.d("decrypt = ", decrypt);

    decrypt = new String(decryptData, "UTF-8");

    return decrypt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the IV before decryption not after it, because it is a parameter of the decryption. Since the IV is prepended to the ciphertext there is no need to save it somewhere else (no need for your `iV` reference).

```
byte[] ciphertextBytes = Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ciphertextBytes, 0, 16);
ciphertextBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertextBytes, 16, ciphertextBytes.length);

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey, "AES");          
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
String decrypt = new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Log outputs - "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption"

Comment: Can you check how long `ciphertextBytes` is before decryption? This is probably an index issue with `Arrays.copyOfRange()`

Comment: Removing the - ivLen (16), makes the decryption work perfectly. Sending a "hey" message, the length of ciphertextBytes is 16

Comment: I've split `IvParameterSpec` constructor into two calls which is what I had before, but thought that I can shave off one line.

Comment: Nope, no change. Same error/warning appears. Again removing the - 16 however made it work.

Comment: You mean `- 16` from the `Arrays.copyOfRange` call? You really should use inline formatting in comments, because I thought that dash was simply a delimiter. I completely misread the documentation. It is `to` and not `length`.

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant. (sorry for the confusion, did not read up on how I could do that).

Comment: It's the back-ticks `\``